# ExecuteScalar, ExcuteReader...There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

There is no open data reader when I call the second sql operation yet I'm getting

> "There is already an open DataReader..." exception.

I can replace the second sql operation (e.g. `ExecuteReader`) with another `ExecuteScaler` with no issues. And I know if I opened a datareader first without closing it and then call `ExecuteScalar`, I would get the exception. (btw, I know you can't update and iterate over the same datareader). It seems you can't use `ExecuteScalar` and `ExecuteReader` with the same `SqlCommand`???

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx WHERE yyy= @t1";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@t1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = uc.CurrentT.ToString();
var empCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (empCount != 1)
    throw new Exception($"Error determining if member exists for tax = {uc.CurrentT}. Expected count = 1, actual count = {empCount}. (Error Code = 1009)");

//member exists and there is only 1 of them...get member's empid
MOS mos = new MOS();                     
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM xxx WHERE yyy = @t1";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@t1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = uc.CurrentT.ToString();

var reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
throw new Exception("foobar here");
```

On `var reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader()`, the "open DataReader" exception gets thrown. The `ExecuteScalar` executes with no issue. I want to use the same command.

Comment: Likely you are using that same connection somewhere else. Maybe in `uc.CurrenT` (whatever that is). Maybe this is code in a loop where `uc.CurrenT` is the current item in an iteration result.

Comment: Definitely no loop present. uc.CurrentT is just an property (of type Int). I hade to change the code because it is sensitive.

Comment: Again you are likely using that connection somewhere else in code not shown. If you want additional help you will have to create an [mcve] and post it. In this case I would recommend a self contained console application. There is nothing else anyone can do for you except state that the above code *should* work but as it is not complete there is no way to see why it is not working *for you*.

Answer (score 0):

You need **MARS** (multiple active result sets).

Otherwise your program will make sure you only have one open cursor on the database. That means iterating through one result set, creating another for each record will fail.

Add this to your connection string: `;MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to activate multiple active result sets.

Comment: Are you saying a ExecuteScaler uses a cursor that isn't properly released? Why do multiple 'ExecuteScalar''s work with no issue but as soon as a ExecuteScalar is followed by a single call to ExecuteReader, the execption is thrown?

Comment: I think you should not reuse a SqlCommand. Create each new command in a `using` block, to make sure the cursor on the database is closed.